# How to eliminate and understand this error warning from vuetify data table slot?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have a Vuetify data table populated from a json data store lke below. But i keep getting this warning:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'usertype' of undefined"
```

The display and code works as expected but I dont like the error warning and want to understand it.

The x.id and typeID are returned by json as strings and strict comparison is used

Eg

```
"characters": [
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Gaia",
  "email": "me@meemee.com",

  "bio": "This really is all about me",
  "image": "",
  "url": "",
  "typeId": "3",
  "active": "1"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Alphomega",
  "email": "me@meemee.com",
  "password": "",
  "bio": "Hub really is all about me",
  "image": "",
  "url": "",
  "typeId": "4",
  "active": "1"
},
```

]

```
"userTypes": [
{
  "id": "3",
  "usertype": "character"
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "usertype": "author"
},
]
```

In my data table I list the characters and have a slot to display the usertype text in the row. So for character 'Gaia' the row would display the row id,name.email, and instead of the typeId it would display the value of the usertype - in this case "character" - from the UserType json data.

To do this is I use this template slot:

```
    <template v-slot:item.type="{ item }">
      <span v-if="userTypes.length">
        {{ userTypes.find(x => x.id === item.typeId).usertype }}
      </span>
    </template>
```

and this is the headers array

```
headers: [
      { text: 'ID', value: 'id' },
      { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
      { text: 'Type', value: 'type' },
      { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
      { text: 'Active', value: 'active' },
      { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
    ],
```

Comment: Maybe just some `typeId` value not found in the `userTypes` array ? Checked that out?

Comment: typeId is in characters and relates to id of userTypes

Comment: Ye, I understand the code. Do you understand my question ?

Comment: Ah now i do / see. In this case there are no empty or non existent ids/typeIds

Comment: Great. Just check again. Because if this was a syntax error or something else, error message would look completely different. This really seems as some of `typeId` values was not found (had no corresponding record in `userTypes` array)

Comment: Thanks Michal you were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is showing this error because your find method will give you undefined when `x.id !== item.typeId`

According to MDN on **Array.find** about its return value: The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, undefined is returned.

```
<template v-slot:item.type="{ item }">
  <span v-if="userTypes.length">
    {{ userTypes.find(x => x.id === item.typeId).usertype }}
  </span>
</template>
```

instead do this

```
<template v-slot:item.type="{ item }">
  <span v-if="userTypes.findIndex(x => x.id === item.typeId) !== -1">
    {{ userTypes.find(x => x.id === item.typeId).usertype }}
  </span>
</template>
```

Array.find on MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Thanks Richard - I was pre-filtering userTypes but it looks like the array still has missing ids and this solves it nicely. Thx for the solution and education